# mbsync slow gmail All Email folder with +100K emails

Tags: email, 21.10

I am using mbsync (isync 1.4.4) on Ubuntu to sync Gmail imap to my local machine.

The Gmail All Mail folder has +100K emails and takes a very long time to sync. Looking at the output from mbsync --debug there is not a lot of network traffic, but it appears that for EVERY email in the All Mail folder there are entries like this:

```
entry (1,1,16,)
...
uid=5750  flags=S    size=0      tuid=?
...
pair (53571,21018)
...
F: * 21018 FETCH (UID 53571 FLAGS (\Seen))
```

The entire output of the --debug command is approx. 24 mb, which I have saved as a log file.

So it appears that the slowness is local.Any idea how I can speed things up?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hello. I am using Ubuntu 21.10.